# Is it possible to filter a TIBQuery?

Tags: delphi, interbase, delphi-10.4-sydney

Using Delphi 10.4.1

I'm not having success filtering a `TIBQuery`, and I'm wondering where I'm going wrong. Hopefully you can point me in the right direction.

Using Interbase 2020, I'm creating these tables in IBConsole.

I have a `TIBQuery` with two fields:

```pascal
LocID: integer;  
PerName: string;  //VarChar[35]
```

The `TIBQuery.Filtered` property is set to true.

At runtime, I do:

```pascal
IBQuery1.Filter := 'LocID = ' + IntToStr(ALocID); // where ALocID is integer;
```

At this point, I would expect to see a filtered record set, but that's not what I'm getting.  The entire unfiltered record set is returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Filter property says how to filter, Filtered says filter or not:

```
IBQuery1.Filtered := false;
IBQuery1.Filter := <something>
IBQuery1.Filtered := true;
```

Comment: So you have to turn the filtered property to false, add the new filter, then set Filtered to true again?  That's wierd, inconvenient & new.  What?  Is this easier than...? whatever it was I used a few years ago?

Comment: No.  Apparently a TIBQuery cannot be filtered.  Which is really peculiar since it has a published "Filtered" property.  What's that for?  What is Embarcadero thinking?  But a FireDAC TFDQuery can in fact be filtered and it appears to work well and as expected.  So I'll just use that instead.